# Matlab- Merge two matrix with different size?

Tags: matlab

I have two different matrix with different size. There is date in `matrix A=[01012011; 01022011]` and some numbers in `matrix B =[1.2 3.1 5.1;2.2 3.3 5.1]`
When I try to merge it , i get  the matrix `C= [ 01012011 1 3 5; 01022011 2 3 5]`. The problem is with the resulting matrix C.i.e.,the resulting matrix round of the values. I want the final matrix `C = [01012011 1.2 3.1 5.1; 01022011 2.2 3.3 5.1]?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are merging your matrices, but you can concatenate them using `C = cat(2,A,B)` or simply `C = [A,B]`, in your 2D case.

Even though Matlab may display rounded values, depending on how your output format is configured (type `help format` for more information on that), the values of matrix C will be correct.

```
A= [01012011; 01022011];
B =[1.2 3.1 5.1;2.2 3.3 5.1];
C = cat(2,A,B);

isequal(B,C(:,2:end)) % will return 1.
```